# рекурсия на всех путях выполнения

Tags: c++, рекурсия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> classes.cpp(37): warning C4717: slovar::~slovar: рекурсия на всех путях выполнения, функция вызовет переполнение стека
>
> classes.cpp(24): warning C4717: slovar::slovar: рекурсия на всех путях выполнения, функция вызовет переполнение стека

...Не понимаю.
Код:
1) pastebin.com/bRASPHTJ
2) pastebin.com/PWZzaR35

Answer (score 4):

```
 1. slovar::slovar()
 2. {
 3.    slovar s;
```

Итак, говорит программа, начнем. Что тут у нас? Строка 1 - отлично, конструктор... Ну-ну. Начнем выполнять его код. Ага, вот она, строка 3. Создать переменную типа `slovar`. Что там мы должны сделать? Вызвать конструктор? нет вопросов, вот же он: строка 1. Что мы должны в нем сделать? ну конечно, строку 3. Создать переменную типа `slovar`.

Что мы должны для этого сделать? Вызвать конструктор? нет вопросов, вот же он: строка 1. Что мы должны в нем сделать? ну конечно, строку 3. Создать переменную типа `slovar`.

Что мы должны для этого сделать? Вызвать конструктор? нет вопросов, вот же он: строка 1. Что мы должны в нем сделать? ну конечно, строку 3. Создать переменную типа `slovar`.

Что мы должны для этого сделать? Вызвать конструктор? нет вопросов, вот же он: строка 1. Что мы должны в нем сделать? ну конечно, строку 3. Создать переменную типа `slovar`.

...

Вопросов нет?

А к вам - есть. Вы не должны приводить вырвиглазные скриншоты, а давать нормальный текст! Исправьте свой вопрос.

Comment: -1 - в ответе недостаточно вложенных вызовов, чтобы вызвать переполнение стека

Comment: @Igor Ну что вы знаете о глубине стека у спрашивающего?... :)

Comment: Если ответ устраивает - исправьте вопрос, как в нем сказано, и пометьте ответ как принятый - птичка слева.

Comment: @Harry 100 байтов?

Comment: Забавно - заминусовал кто-то действительно за недостаточность вложенных вызовов? :)

Comment: @Harry имея такой плохой вопрос и хороший ответ, скорее вам стоит вопрос исправить, чтобы он соответствовал ответу ;-)

Comment: @Kromster Чукча не вопрошатель, чукча отвечатель... :)